# Preserve default image name on download link

Tags: javascript, html

I created a download link, with a base 64 encoded image it works but I need to preserve the orginal file name and now I have to set it, the image is dynamic I can't hardcode the file name.

```
downloadImage: function(){
        var image_url = document.getElementById('image').src;
        const a = document.createElement('a')
        a.href = image_url
        a.download ='here I need to preserve the original file name';
        document.body.appendChild(a)
        a.click()
        document.body.removeChild(a)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image src is base64, there isn't a name to get. You can make one up. The following is if the image src is actually a file path

```
downloadImage: function(){
        var image_url = document.getElementById('image').src;
        const a = document.createElement('a')
        a.href = image_url
        let name = image_url.split("/");
        name = name[name.length-1];
        a.download =name;
        document.body.appendChild(a)
        a.click()
        document.body.removeChild(a)
    }
```